# Bash wait for async job in non-interactive shell without tty / job control

Tags: bash

I'm trying to run a number of jobs in parallel using a bash script run in a non-interactive shell.

I do not want the main script to terminate until all child processes have terminated as well.

Here's an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
while (( "$#" )); do
  some_long_task "$1" &
done

for job in `jobs -p`; do
  wait $job || echo 'Could not wait for job: ' $job
done
```

which gives me `bash:no job control in this shell` as an error and terminates before finishing the jobs.

How can I have bash wait for each of the child processes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`wait` without parameters waits for all child processes, which seems to be just what you need. Seems to work fine with job control disabled.

Answer (score 0):

you can have something like this

```
   while (( "$#" )); do
      some_long_task "$1" &
      eval pid='$pid $!'
    done

    wait $pid
```

Thanks